# Angular Material custom input validation message not showing with mat-stepper

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, mat-stepper, mat-input

I implemented custom control based on official guides using `ControlValueAccessor`:

- https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control
- https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/

The issue that validation error is not showing until we touch our custom field. In my case I have an issue with [Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview), but it also not working when I do `this.form.markAllAsTouched()`

[image: Error example]

I provide example below based on official custom Phone field. Click "Next" with empty fields.

[Example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubmjnt?file=src/app/form-field-custom-control-example.ts)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the function errroState. You can add the condition ngControl.invalid and mark as touched is the ngControl is touched using

```
  get errorState(): boolean {
    const touched=!!this.ngControl?.touched;
    if (touched!=this.touched)
    {
      this.touched=touched;
      this.stateChanges.next();
    }
    return (this.parts.invalid || !!this.ngControl?.invalid) && this.touched;
  }
```

Then if you mark as touched the FormControl, you see the error

```
<button type="button" mat-button matStepperNext 
   (click)="form.markAllAsTouched()" >Next</button>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubmjnt-dnems4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform-field-custom-control-example.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the `MyTelInput` property `touched` from **false** to **true**

```
export class MyTelInput
  implements ControlValueAccessor, MatFormFieldControl<MyTel>, OnDestroy
{
.
.
.
touched = true; //change from false to true
.
.
}
```

Try look also in the angular material docs for more info

https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control#errorstate

[Solution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPn56.png)